# Creating a structure point and then calculating distance between two points

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, cell-array, euclidean-distance

I need some help figuring how do i create a structure point.

I need two fields x and y then I want to create a function that calculates the distance between these two points.

What I have right now is:

```
function [ out ] = pointDist3( pointpair1, pointpair2)
%FUNCTION pointDist3 takes in any two pairs of points and 
% Calling sequence:
%   out = pointDist3(varargin)
%DEFINE VARIABLES
% minargs, maxargs = error checking variables 
% pointpair1 = structure containing fields for point 1: x1 and y1
% pointpair2 = structure containing fields for point 2: x2 and y2
% out = structure containing field distance

%CHECK FOR VALID INPUT
if ~isfield(pointpair1,'x', pointpair2, 'x' ) || ~isfield(pointpair1,'y', pointpair2, 'y')
    error('Input argument does not contain fields "x" and "y" for both points');
else

    out = sqrt((pointpair1.x-pointpair2.x)^2+(pointpair1.y-pointpair2.y)^2);

   end

end
```

Comment: What is the question? Does your code work or not?

Comment: I am trying to do this question: Define a structure point containing two fields, x and y. The x field will contain the x-position of the point, and the y field will contain the y-position of the point. Then write a function pointDist3 that accepts two points and returns the distance between the two points on the Cartesian plane. Be sure to check the number of input arguments in your function.  

<p>No it does not work because it get stuck at the if statement. </p>

Comment: I get this error
'Error using isfield'
'Too many input arguments.'

'Error in pointDist3 (line 28)
if ~isfield(pointpair1,'x', pointpair2, 'x' ) || ~isfield(pointpair1,'y', pointpair2, 'y')'

Comment: Look up the `isfield` documentation, you are using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David for the fix! Here's the working version

```
function [ out ] = pointDist3( pointpair1, pointpair2)
%FUNCTION pointDist3 takes in any two pairs of points and 
% Calling sequence:
%   out = pointDist3(varargin)
%DEFINE VARIABLES
% minargs, maxargs = error checking variables 
% pointpair1 = structure containing fields for point 1: x1 and y1
% pointpair2 = structure containing fields for point 2: x2 and y2
% out = structure containing field distance

%CHECK FOR VALID INPUT
    if ~isfield(pointpair1,'x')|| ~isfield(pointpair2, 'x' ) || ~isfield(pointpair1,'y') || ~isfield(pointpair2, 'y')
        error('Input argument does not contain fields "x" and "y" for both points');
    else

        out = sqrt((pointpair1.x-pointpair2.x)^2+(pointpair1.y-pointpair2.y)^2);
    end 
end
```

TESTER:

```
   >> pointA.x = 3

pointA = 

    x: 3

>> pointA.y =4

pointA = 

    x: 3
    y: 4

>> pointB.x=4

pointB = 

    x: 4

>> pointB.y=5

pointB = 

    x: 4
    y: 5

>> pointDist3(pointA, pointB)

ans =

    1.4142
```